# I need to get user image from firebase to show it on ViewHolder after user uplaoded thier image in profile activity

Tags: android, image, firebase

I have a profile activity that user upload their profile images, user uploads 2 images ( back and front) the images are showing fine in the profile activity, but I also want to show one of this image (back or front) in another activity ( ViewHolder activity ). I have tried many things but couldn't figure out as i am only testing how firebase works, I really appreciate if someone can help me here.

Here is my profile activity where user upload images to firebase.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageView backimage;
private CircleImageView profileimage;
TextView totalscore,correctattempts,totalattempts,user_name,java_score,python_score,php_score,android_score,phone_number;

private Uri filepath;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
private int id;

StorageReference storageReference;
DatabaseReference users,defaultimages,scoretbl;
String Storage_Path = "All_Image_Uploads/";

// Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
public static final String Database_Path = "All_Image_Uploads_Database";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    defaultimages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database_Path");

    java_score=findViewById(R.id.javascore);
    phone_number=findViewById(R.id.user_phonenumber);
    python_score=findViewById(R.id.pythonscore);
    php_score=findViewById(R.id.phpscore);
    android_score =findViewById(R.id.androidscore);

    backimage = findViewById(R.id.header_cover_image);
    profileimage=findViewById(R.id.user_profile_photo);
    totalattempts=findViewById(R.id.questionsattempted);
    correctattempts=findViewById(R.id.correctattempts);
    totalscore=findViewById(R.id.totalscore);
    user_name =findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);

    backimage.setOnClickListener(this);
    profileimage.setOnClickListener(this);
    user_name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    user_name.setText(Common.currentUser.getUserName());

    phone_number.setText(Common.currentUser.getEmail());




    users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           /* String score=dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentuser.getUsername()).child("totalScore").getValue().toString();
            totalscore.setText(score);
            String tattempts=dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentuser.getUsername()).child("questionsAttempted").getValue().toString();
            totalattempts.setText(tattempts);
            String cattempts=dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentuser.getUsername()).child("correctAttempts").getValue().toString();
            correctattempts.setText(cattempts);
            phone_number.setText(Common.currentuser.getEmail());

            */
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()).child("pathtobackimage").getValue().toString())
                    .into(backimage);

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()).child("pathtoprofileimage").getValue().toString())
                    .into(profileimage);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


   /*

   scoretbl.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child("Java").exists())
            java_score.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Java").child("score").getValue().toString());
            if(dataSnapshot.child("Python").exists())
            python_score.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Python").child("score").getValue().toString());
            if(dataSnapshot.child("PHP").exists())
            php_score.setText(dataSnapshot.child("PHP").child("score").getValue().toString());
            if(dataSnapshot.child("Android").exists())
            android_score.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Android").child("score").getValue().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    */

}

private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST&&resultCode ==RESULT_OK
            && data !=null && data.getData()!= null){
        filepath = data.getData();
        if(id==R.id.header_cover_image)
            Picasso.with(this).load(filepath).into(backimage);
        else
            Picasso.with(this).load(filepath).into(profileimage);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.header_cover_image:{
            id = R.id.header_cover_image;
            chooseImage();
            uploadImageback();

            break;
        }
        case R.id.user_profile_photo:{
            id = R.id.user_profile_photo;
            chooseImage();
            uploadImageprofile();

            break;
        }
    }
}

private void uploadImageback() {

    final StorageReference backref = storageReference.child("images/").
            child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()+"/"+ Common.currentUser.getUserName()+"back");

    if(filepath!=null){

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading..");
        progressDialog.show();

        backref.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                backref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        users.child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()).child("pathtobackimage").setValue(uri.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Not Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
            }
        });
    }

}

private void uploadImageprofile() {

    if(filepath!=null){

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading.. ");
        progressDialog.show();

        final StorageReference profileref = storageReference.child("images/").
                child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()+"/"+ Common.currentUser.getUserName()+"profile");
        profileref.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                profileref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        users.child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()).child("pathtoprofileimage").setValue(uri.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Profile Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Profile not Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+" %");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

and I want to show one of these image in my ViewHolder activity as you can see the text view (name and score are showing) which is coming from a ranking Fragment activity

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView name_text,score_text;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public RankingViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    score_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.score_text);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);

}
```

}

and the Fragment activity

```
public class RankingFragment extends Fragment {

View myFragment;
FirebaseDatabase database;
RecyclerView rankingList;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking,RankingViewHolder> adapter;
DatabaseReference questionScore,rankingTable;
int sum = 0; //score is default by zero

public static RankingFragment newInstance(){
    RankingFragment rankingFragment = new RankingFragment();
    return rankingFragment ;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    questionScore = database.getReference("Question_Score");
    rankingTable = database.getReference("Ranking");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranking,container,false);

    rankingList = (RecyclerView) myFragment.findViewById(R.id.ranking_list);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rankingList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //Using orderByChild method , this will sort the ranking in ascending order
    //reverse the data by using layout manager
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    rankingList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    updateScore(Common.currentUser.getUserName(), new RankingCallBack<Ranking>() {
        @Override
        public void callBack(Ranking ranking) {
            //Ranking Score update
            rankingTable.child(ranking.getUserName())
                    .setValue(ranking);
            // showRanking();
        }
    });

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ranking, RankingViewHolder>(
            Ranking.class,
            R.layout.ranking_layout,
            RankingViewHolder.class,
            rankingTable.orderByChild("score")
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(RankingViewHolder viewHolder, final Ranking model, int position) {


            viewHolder.name_text.setText(model.getUserName());
            viewHolder.score_text.setText(String.valueOf(model.getScore()));

            //prevent crash when user click
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Intent scoreDetail = new Intent(getActivity(),Score_Detail.class);
                    scoreDetail.putExtra("viewUser",model.getUserName());
                    startActivity(scoreDetail);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rankingList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return myFragment;
}



private void updateScore(final String userName, final RankingCallBack<Ranking> callBack) {
    questionScore.orderByChild("user").equalTo(userName)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Question_Score quest = data.getValue(Question_Score.class);
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(quest.getScore());

                    }

                    Ranking ranking = new Ranking(userName,sum);
                    callBack.callBack(ranking);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

}
 and here is my Ranking class

```
public class Ranking {

private String userName;
private long score;
private String urlProfilePic;
public Ranking(){
}

public Ranking(String userName, long score, String pathtobackimage ) {

    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
    this.urlProfilePic = pathtobackimage;
}

public String getUrlProfilePic() {
    return urlProfilePic;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public long getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(long score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

}

Here the screen shot to help more how I wanted

[image: My Profile activity]

[image: and here is my ranking activity where I want the user profile image to be shown]

Answer (score 0):

I put my comment in answer field because of this restriction: 'You must have 50 reputation to comment'.

Anyway, back to your question. One solution would be to save the current user 'key' to a `SharedPreference` file. In your new `Activity`, use that 'key' to retrieve the data from Firebase.

## EDIT: Added solution

Quoted: "...and I want to show one of these image in my ViewHolder activity as you can see the text view (name and score are showing) which is coming from a ranking Fragment activity..."

Solution: Search for `fixme`. In `RankingViewHolder` class, add:

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends ...
  //...
  public TextView name_text, score_text;
  public ImageView profileImageView;  //fixme
  //...

  public RankingViewHolder(View itemView) {
    //...
    score_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
    profileImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_view);  //fixme
    //...
```

Inside `populateViewHolder()`

```
    viewHolder.score_text.setText(String.valueOf(model.getScore()));

    Picasso.with(getContext())  //fixme
        .load(Common.currentUser.getUrlProfilePic())  //fixme
        .into(viewHolder.profileImageView);  //fixme
```

Inside `RankingFragment` class, since you are already using `Common.currentUser.getUserName()`, might as well create another variable under it to store the url link to the user's profile picture, and retrieve the link via `Common.currentUser.getUrlProfilePic()`.

## EDIT#2:

The images stored in FB storage have this links:
gs://**FIXME_FIREBASE**.com/images/userName/userNameback.jpeg
gs://**FIXME_FIREBASE**.com/images/userName/userNameprofile.jpeg

However to use in Picasso, need this kind of links:
[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*FIXME*/o/*FIXME*/images/userName/userNameback.jpeg?alt=media&token=*FIXME*](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/_FIXME_/o/_FIXME_/images/userName/userNameback.jpeg?alt=media&token=_FIXME_)

Question is how to get that?

One solution is that after you successfully upload the image, get the download url (example below).
The tricky part is that the download url is not immediately available, and you have to use `.getMetadata()`, `.getDownloadUrl()` to do that.
Once the url is received, you have to figure out how to save this link to the user's profile in your FB database.

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

      StorageMetadata storageMetadata = taskSnapshot.getMetadata();

      StorageReference reference = storageMetadata.getReference();
      reference.getDownloadUrl()  // Get the download URL for the file
          .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
              Log.i(TAG, uri.toString());  //fixme: save this to user's profile
            }
          });
    }
```

Inside `populateViewHolder`, you are using `Ranking` model that contains the username and score.
Modify that `Ranking` model class to add an additional String variable `urlProfilePic` that contains the url to the user's image (above result), and generate the getter for it called `getUrlProfilePic()`. Then you can use it in this way inside the `populateViewHolder`:

```
   viewHolder.score_text.setText(String.valueOf(model.getScore()));

    Picasso.with(getContext())
        .load(model.getUrlProfilePic())  //fixme
        .into(viewHolder.profileImageView);
```

Comment: The user profile activity already have saved the image to firebase and its showing fine, but I want to show the same user profile image in another activity without asking user to upload again. If you look at the code you see user upload image and its showing on the same activity so how to show it on that viewholder I created. its a simple question but I am totally new to java and I am learner forgive me

Comment: I need to add this code Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentUser.getUserName()).child("pathtoprofileimage").getValue().toString())
                    .into(profileimage); to the RankingViewHolder just under the user name and score,

Comment: Yes we almost there body, I have tried this code              Picasso.with(getContext())  //fixme
                        .load(Common.currentUser.getPhotoUrl())  //fixme
                        .into(viewHolder.profileImageView);  //fixme but I am getting a blank image looks like its pointing to the wrong table on the database as I explained I am totally new to java, firebase and android too so am not sure why we calling current user here as I want all users image to be shown on that view holder, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: My profile activity saves the user profile images in the firebase storage as /images/userName/userNameback.jpeg and /images/userName/userNameprofile.jpeg so to get this images is what I am lost here, can Picasso get all users profile images in that table/storage and show it in that Viewholder? Please help.. I tried Picasso, Glide but getting error, I am sure all I need is just how to get the all users image and not current user from my storage. I thought getting from my profile activity is easier but I was wrong sorry! totally noob I am,Thanks you.

Comment: Here I have updated my question and added a screen shot, if you look I am getting user email, image, name, in the profile but its calling currentUser but I think on theother viewHolder (ranking fragment) it need all users so no need to use currentUser? please forgive me for being a pain. Thanks.

Comment: See EDIT#2 for an update. 

As for image not loading issue, one way to quick test is to visit the Firebase console, get the image link (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...), hardcode in your source, just to test out whether image display is successful.

My suggestions would be for you to test each individual tasks you planned to do, rather them lump everything together. Ensure that you grasp how to use Picasso, FB Storage/Database, RecyclerView, ViewHolder separately first before attempt to merge them together.

Comment: TBH, firebase is not really beginner friendly, because results returned are not immediately available. You have to figure out how to write/read to a particular record, write/read from all records etc. But is a good learning experience.

Comment: Yes you right about the FB not a user friendly at all but I am getting there, I have tried just basic url string  like this and it loads the url image in the viewHolder without aproblem, and I also forget to mention that after the image is stored in the FB storage (/images/userName/userNameprofile.jpeg) and the back image, it also create a table in my FB database that have the direct image url inside Users table and then in every user it have a table of that profile image called pathtobackimage and pathtoprofileimage,

Comment: looks like this (pathtobackimage: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lea..."
pathtoprofileimage: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lea..."
) as it showing on the [profile activity, I really thank you for your help sir.

Comment: String url="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learnbravanese.appspot.com/o/images%2Fmoh2%2Fmoh2back?alt=media&token=d97130a4-c6ac-409f-a0ad-71fdcdea1e97";//Retrieved url as mentioned above

                 Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(viewHolder.profileImageView); Like this works but its loading url direct not profile image for specific user

Comment: Tried your new example Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(model.getUrlProfilePic())  //fixme
                        .into(viewHolder.profileImageView);
and its still not loading the user UrlProfilePic , I have added my ranking model activity.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the values are incorrect populated.
Try to use Log.d() to dump the user's values inside the `populateViewHolder`.
Verify that the values of userName, score, urlProfilePic are correct for that particular user. My guess is that the display ui codes are already working since hardcoding the links worked. Just that the values are incorrectly populated.

Comment: Thanks body for your help, I am really new to all this and never used Log D as I check all the logs error from the Android Studio Logcat or run for any errors, not sure how to write but I have tried like this Log.d(TAG, "populateViewHolder(final RankingViewHolder viewHolder, final Ranking model, int position" + position); is this correct? but I didnt see anything about my firebase.

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat